# How do I import .pgn data in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

For a school project I am creating an artificial neural network that I'm going to train with data from lichess.org, an online chess-playing website that has all of it's 1.5 billion games open source and ready for download.

I downloaded 11 million games as a 10gb text file, and now want to somehow access them in my PyCharm project: Either by assigning it as a string to a variable or any other method that lets me directly change and access that text.

I have already uploaded the pgn to my project in pycharm:

[image: Image of the project folder with pgn and main.py]

This is a sample of what the pgn looks like inside:

[image: Image of chess text]
There are about 11 million of those game records.

Thank you very much! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to import the file, it will be accessible from python without any extra steps

Comment: @mousetail ok, that's good! Can you please tell me how I would access it? Like let's say I wanted to print it, would I simply type:

 print(lichess_db_standard_rated_2017-03.pgn)?

Thanks!

Comment: See https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python